# Switch from Up Arrow to Hamburger Icon on Button Click in ActionBar

Tags: android

I want to change the **Hamburger icon** on Android ActionBar to **Up arrow** on button click, and also to change the Up arrow back to Hamburger icon on another button click event.

I have tried using ,

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

However, none of them works. I can change the Hamburger icon to up arrow easily using,

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But **not the vice-versa**.

Also, how do I **override the home button control**?

I mean when a certain layout is open, I want the up arrow to close that layout on click and not to call the navigation drawer.

Please help.

Comment: Hmm. I've the exact same issue. Did you solve both of these, or are they still open?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following piece of code:

```
    ViewGroup home =(ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent();
    // get the first child (up imageview)
    ((ImageView) home.getChildAt(0)).setImageResource(your image here);
```

Sorry, no privileges to comment so updating the answer. Well, since this is an imageView, I am assuming you could place an onClickListener and toggle between using the hamburger and the back arrow. This should be close to the material design's animated hamburger behavior.

Comment: But if I explicitly set a icon like that, won't I lose the animated hamburger icon which transforms to up arrow on drawer open, in Material Design?

Comment: But how do I achieve the animation? Any other ideas? Is there a way to set the home button to the default hamburger icon with some method?